# MongoDB MMS Can't modify an existing, standalone deployment

Tags: mongodb-mms

I'm just starting to try out the cloud-based MMS service and I'm testing it on an existing, standalone MongoDB deployment running on AWS.  I was able to install the agent and begin monitoring - that all works fine.

However, when I got to the Deployment tab and click the first Processes view, the Actions menu does not show me everything.  I get:

- Properties
- Performance Metrics
- Connect to this instance
- Monitor Settings
- Remove from MMS

There is no "Modify" or "Shutdown" or any other options for editing. It is an older version of MongoDB (2.4.11 - and MMS notes this by styling it in red and providing a popup that says it's old) and, again, it was an existing, standalone deployment.  I was interested in using MMS to monitor and hopefully upgrade.  Are there limitations with MMS and this type of deployment?  Is there some setting or other that would be preventing modifications?

Answer (score 0):

In MMS you can only manage new instances created with MMS. For other MongoDB instances you would have to import your deployment.

> Until today, it was only possible to manage new deployments with MMS Automation. Starting today, you can get the benefits of Automation on the vast majority of your pre-existing deployments. Automation allows you to turn long and complicated manual processes into single click operations with MMS.

You can read more on the MongoDB MMS Blog:
[Importing an existing instance to MMS](http://blog.mms.mongodb.com/post/111860709590/introduction-to-import-existing-deployment-for)

There is also a checklist, however upgrading manually might be quicker.